# Tokens regex: expression for last token/no more tokens

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am writing a tokens regex where I need to check that there are no more tokens following. I am using []{0} to do that, but it does not work.

Specifically, for a phrase like this, "on Tuesday or after", my tokens regex is

/on|at|for/ [ner:/DATE|TIME/] /and|or/ /after|later/ []{0}

But, this expression also matches "on Tuesday or after Thursday", which is semantically different from "on Tuesday or after". Any ideas how to check for no tokens following, or to re-write the regex to match the first phrase and not the second? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:
  /on|at|for/ [ner:/DATE|TIME/] /and|or/ /after|later/ $

Comment: Thanks, Angel, that did it. Nice to know that tokens regex can handle special characters like $ or ^ properly. And thanks for building it, too.

Comment: Angel, is there anything like (/sea/ ([{word: view}] | $)) to match sea followed by either view or sea as the last token. I have tried this, but sadly it doesn't work.